# webapp in azure with 2/3 slots which can deploy in specified environment (DEV/CAN) with ARM template

Tags: web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I have tried with one slot concept with tagging one environment but unable to write a template for 2 slots.

Help me with a webapp in azure with 2/3 slots which can deploy in specified environment (DEV/CAN) with ARM template

Answer (score 0):

To create a Microsoft.Web/sites/slots resource, add the following JSON to the resources section of your template.

```html
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "kind": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {},
  "properties": {
    "enabled": "boolean",
    "hostNameSslStates": [
      {
        "name": "string",
        "sslState": "string",
        "virtualIP": "string",
        "thumbprint": "string",
        "toUpdate": "boolean",
        "hostType": "string"
      }
    ],
    "serverFarmId": "string",
    "reserved": "boolean",
    "isXenon": "boolean",
    "hyperV": "boolean",
    "siteConfig": {
      "numberOfWorkers": "integer",
      "defaultDocuments": [
        "string"
      ],
      "netFrameworkVersion": "string",
      "phpVersion": "string",
      "pythonVersion": "string",
      "nodeVersion": "string",
      "linuxFxVersion": "string",
      "windowsFxVersion": "string",
      "requestTracingEnabled": "boolean",
      "requestTracingExpirationTime": "string",
      "remoteDebuggingEnabled": "boolean",
      "remoteDebuggingVersion": "string",
      "httpLoggingEnabled": "boolean",
      "logsDirectorySizeLimit": "integer",
      "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": "boolean",
      "publishingUsername": "string",
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "value": "string"
        }
      ],
      "azureStorageAccounts": {},
      "connectionStrings": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "connectionString": "string",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "handlerMappings": [
        {
          "extension": "string",
          "scriptProcessor": "string",
          "arguments": "string"
        }
      ],
      "documentRoot": "string",
      "scmType": "string",
      "use32BitWorkerProcess": "boolean",
      "webSocketsEnabled": "boolean",
      "alwaysOn": "boolean",
      "javaVersion": "string",
      "javaContainer": "string",
      "javaContainerVersion": "string",
      "appCommandLine": "string",
      "managedPipelineMode": "string",
      "virtualApplications": [
        {
          "virtualPath": "string",
          "physicalPath": "string",
          "preloadEnabled": "boolean",
          "virtualDirectories": [
            {
              "virtualPath": "string",
              "physicalPath": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "loadBalancing": "string",
      "experiments": {
        "rampUpRules": [
          {
            "actionHostName": "string",
            "reroutePercentage": "number",
            "changeStep": "number",
            "changeIntervalInMinutes": "integer",
            "minReroutePercentage": "number",
            "maxReroutePercentage": "number",
            "changeDecisionCallbackUrl": "string",
            "name": "string"
          }
        ]
      },
      "limits": {
        "maxPercentageCpu": "number",
        "maxMemoryInMb": "integer",
        "maxDiskSizeInMb": "integer"
      },
      "autoHealEnabled": "boolean",
      "autoHealRules": {
        "triggers": {
          "requests": {
            "count": "integer",
            "timeInterval": "string"
          },
          "privateBytesInKB": "integer",
          "statusCodes": [
            {
              "status": "integer",
              "subStatus": "integer",
              "win32Status": "integer",
              "count": "integer",
              "timeInterval": "string"
            }
          ],
          "slowRequests": {
            "timeTaken": "string",
            "count": "integer",
            "timeInterval": "string"
          }
        },
        "actions": {
          "actionType": "string",
          "customAction": {
            "exe": "string",
            "parameters": "string"
          },
          "minProcessExecutionTime": "string"
        }
      },
      "tracingOptions": "string",
      "vnetName": "string",
      "cors": {
        "allowedOrigins": [
          "string"
        ],
        "supportCredentials": "boolean"
      },
      "push": {
        "kind": "string",
        "properties": {
          "isPushEnabled": "boolean",
          "tagWhitelistJson": "string",
          "tagsRequiringAuth": "string",
          "dynamicTagsJson": "string"
        }
      },
      "apiDefinition": {
        "url": "string"
      },
      "autoSwapSlotName": "string",
      "localMySqlEnabled": "boolean",
      "managedServiceIdentityId": "integer",
      "xManagedServiceIdentityId": "integer",
      "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
        {
          "ipAddress": "string",
          "subnetMask": "string",
          "vnetSubnetResourceId": "string",
          "action": "string",
          "tag": "string",
          "priority": "integer",
          "name": "string",
          "description": "string"
        }
      ],
      "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": [
        {
          "ipAddress": "string",
          "subnetMask": "string",
          "vnetSubnetResourceId": "string",
          "action": "string",
          "tag": "string",
          "priority": "integer",
          "name": "string",
          "description": "string"
        }
      ],
      "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": "boolean",
      "http20Enabled": "boolean",
      "minTlsVersion": "string",
      "ftpsState": "string",
      "reservedInstanceCount": "integer"
    },
    "scmSiteAlsoStopped": "boolean",
    "hostingEnvironmentProfile": {
      "id": "string"
    },
    "clientAffinityEnabled": "boolean",
    "clientCertEnabled": "boolean",
    "clientCertExclusionPaths": "string",
    "hostNamesDisabled": "boolean",
    "containerSize": "integer",
    "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": "integer",
    "cloningInfo": {
      "correlationId": "string",
      "overwrite": "boolean",
      "cloneCustomHostNames": "boolean",
      "cloneSourceControl": "boolean",
      "sourceWebAppId": "string",
      "sourceWebAppLocation": "string",
      "hostingEnvironment": "string",
      "appSettingsOverrides": {},
      "configureLoadBalancing": "boolean",
      "trafficManagerProfileId": "string",
      "trafficManagerProfileName": "string"
    },
    "httpsOnly": "boolean",
    "redundancyMode": "string",
    "geoDistributions": [
      {
        "location": "string",
        "numberOfWorkers": "integer"
      }
    ]
  },
  "identity": {
    "type": "string",
    "userAssignedIdentities": {}
  },
  "resources": []
}
```